# Tagging items in lists

Tags: python, nearest-neighbor

So I have multiple items in a list and I need to "tag them"
So basically lets say we have a list

```py
fruits = [apple, banana, orange]
```

and now we ask the user for tags like: taste, color...

And for example when user says `"Sour, Orange, Circle"` It will output `best result: Orange`

Any tips how to do it?

I tried using 2 lists.
But really not sure how to code it

Comment: Does it have to be a list?  A dictionary seems like a better solution.

Comment: It doesn't really

Comment: It will be beneficial if you can share your structure or what have you tried, so that community can leverage that and provide probable solution(s).

Answer (score 0):

I see two ways to do this, assuming they need to be in a list

**A List of Classes**

```py
class Fruit:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

fruits = []

apple = Fruit("apple")
apple.taste = "good"
apple.color = "red"

fruits.append(apple)
```

**A List of Dicts**

```py
fruits = []

apple = {
    "name": "apple"
    "color": "red",
    "taste": "good"
}

fruits.append(apple)
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the approach is to use user defined types or classes.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Fruit:
    name: str
    color: Set[str]
    taste: Set[str]

# Now insertion of the data set
list_of_fruits = [Fruit("apple", "red", "sweet"), ...]
# user query 
# In this it would be something like
input_color = input()
input_taste = input()
# etc.

# search query is nothing but the combination of the user inputs 
def find(search_query, list_of_fruits):
    # logic to find the exact element or best match in the given list of fruits
    # few of the use cases:
    # 1/ must have so and so color taste may
    # 2/ must have so and so color taste must have so and so
    # 3/ atleast one should match
    # 4/ atmost one should match
    pass
```

Comment: This appears to assume that each type of fruit has exactly one colour and one taste.

Comment: I should have stated that as assumption, it is just type hinting, rather than `str` it should be `Set`

Answer (score 0):

```
fruits = {
    "apple": {
        "taste": ["sweet", "tart"],
        "color": ["red", "green"],
    },
    "orange": {
        "taste": ["sweet"],
        "color": ["orange"],
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map each fruit to a list of tags; then return the fruits with highest count of matching tags.

```py
from collections import Counter

fruits = {
  'apple': {'red', 'green', 'yellow', 'round', 'sweet'},
  'banana': {'yellow', 'sweet', 'peel'},
  'orange': {'orange', 'round', 'sour', 'sweet'},
}

def find_best_fruits(fruits, wanted_tags, k=1):
    wanted_tags = set(wanted_tags)
    scores = Counter({fruit: len(wanted_tags & fruit_tags) for fruit, fruit_tags in fruits.items()})
    return scores.most_common(k)

wanted_tags = ['sour', 'orange', 'round']

print('Best fruit for ', wanted_tags, ':')
print( find_best_fruits(fruits, wanted_tags) )

print('Best 3 fruits for ', wanted_tags, ':')
print( find_best_fruits(fruits, wanted_tags, 3) )
```

Output:

```
Best fruit for  ['sour', 'orange', 'round'] :
[('orange', 3)]
Best 3 fruits for  ['sour', 'orange', 'round'] :
[('orange', 3), ('apple', 1), ('banana', 0)]
```